# Android Room Persistence Library Proguard Configuration

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard, android-room

I am using Android Room Persistence Library 1.0.0-alpha5.
When compiling with ProGuard I am  getting the following error.

```
Warning:android.arch.persistence.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource: can't find superclass or interface android.arch.util.paging.CountedDataSource
Warning:android.arch.persistence.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource: can't find referenced class android.arch.util.paging.CountedDataSource
Warning:android.arch.persistence.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource$1: can't find referenced method 'void invalidate()' in program class android.arch.persistence.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource
Warning:there were 5 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

My ProGuard Configuration for Room is as follows

```
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.Nullable
-dontwarn javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
# Platform calls Class.forName on types which do not exist on Android to     determine platform.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
# Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
# Retain generic type information for use by reflection by converters     and adapters.
-keepattributes Signature
# Retain declared checked exceptions for use by a Proxy instance.
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keep class android.content.**
-dontwarn android.content.**
-keep class android.animation.**
-dontwarn android.animation.**
-keep class me.panavtec.drawableview.**
-dontwarn me.panavtec.drawableview.**
-keep class javax.annotation.concurrent.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.concurrent.**
-keep class android.arch.persistence.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource
-keep interface android.arch.persistence.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource
-keep class android.arch.util.paging.CountedDataSource
-keep interface android.arch.util.paging.CountedDataSource
```

I need help in fixing this error. I believe ProGuard Configuration was not required prior to Alpha 3 and I did not test alpha 4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add the following lines in the proguard instead of `keep`

```
-dontwarn android.arch.util.paging.CountedDataSource
-dontwarn android.arch.persistence.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource
```

Comment: It worked.
I am always a bit sceptical in using dontwarn in proguard for some reason :P
Thanks a lot :D