# Release build: transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, android-proguard

Generate signed APK:

```
Note: there were 8 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
Note: there were 4 accesses to class members by means of introspection.
Warning: there were 5 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.

transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED
```

[Full Gradle log is here](https://gist.github.com/tim4dev/e7784d6938e9f8423eab62b463284519).

[My app build.gradle is here](https://gist.github.com/tim4dev/53ba45f950d2e19d6f2970b7e4127ac6).

**UPD**. [Stacktrace is here](https://gist.github.com/tim4dev/61e2c9af87c6761d4fa87c09483de84b).

If I use the -ignorewarnings option, then the app crashes on some versions of the Android.

Presumably after go to Room, I stopped generate signed APK.
Also I had to do downgrade com.google.firebase, com.google.android.gms:play-services from 11.0.4 to 11.0.2

Two simple questions (for those who know).

The log says:

```
Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. 
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

**Q1. Where in Android Studio can I specify "--stacktrace", "--info or --debug" options ?**

**Q2. How (I read the log) I must find out what classes are missing? Where should I look? What to look for?**

Comment: Use proguard config from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45344040/android-room-persistence-library-proguard-configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: In your command line from root of the project: `./gradlew build --stacktrace`

Q2: You should fix this warnings:

```
Warning: android.arch.persistence.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource: can't find superclass or interface android.arch.util.paging.CountedDataSource
Warning: android.arch.persistence.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource: can't find referenced class android.arch.util.paging.CountedDataSource
Warning: android.arch.persistence.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource: can't find referenced class android.arch.util.paging.CountedDataSource
Warning: android.arch.persistence.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource: can't find referenced class android.arch.util.paging.CountedDataSource
Warning: android.arch.persistence.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource: can't find referenced class android.arch.util.paging.CountedDataSource
Warning: android.arch.persistence.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource$1: can't find referenced method 'void invalidate()' in program class android.arch.persistence.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource
```

And you can try add this to your proguard file:

```
-dontwarn android.arch.util.paging.CountedDataSource
-dontwarn android.arch.persistence.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see here whats classes are missing

```
Warning: android.arch.persistence.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource: can't find superclass or interface android.arch.util.paging.CountedDataSource
Warning: android.arch.persistence.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource: can't find referenced class android.arch.util.paging.CountedDataSource
Warning: android.arch.persistence.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource: can't find referenced class android.arch.util.paging.CountedDataSource
Warning: android.arch.persistence.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource: can't find referenced class android.arch.util.paging.CountedDataSource
Warning: android.arch.persistence.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource: can't find referenced class android.arch.util.paging.CountedDataSource
Warning: android.arch.persistence.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource$1: can't find referenced method 'void invalidate()' in program class android.arch.persistence.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource
```

Take a look how to implement **proguard** to handle this classes, you can try add this to your **proguard-rules.pro** file:

```
-dontwarn android.arch.**
```

or you can disable proguard from your build ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45491643/release-build-transformclassesandresourceswithproguardforrelease-failed#))